# How to prove that N(u) = 1 if and only if u is a unit in $Z[\sqrt-5]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

The norm of an element $u=a+b\sqrt-5$ in $Z[\sqrt-5]$ is defined as $N(u)= a^2 +5b^2$, now if $N(u) = 1$ then $a^2+5b^2 = 1$ but then how would i prove that it's a unit !?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that norm has the following property. $N(\alpha)=\alpha \bar{\alpha}$. Thus when $N(\alpha)=1$, this means $\alpha \bar{\alpha}=1$, hence $\alpha$ is a unit.

Comment: Conversely, if $u$ is a unit then we know there exits $v$ such that $uv =1$ and so $N(uv) = N(1) = 1$ and hence $N(u)=1$ is that true ? Thanks alot

Comment: @leo Yes that is true but you have to use two things here: $N(uv)=N(u) N(v)$ and also the fact that $N(u) \in \mathbb{Z}$ to draw the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, thanks again

Answer (score -2):

$N(u)=1$ implies $|a|=1$ and $b=0$, so $u=-1$ or $u=1$, hence $u$ must be a unit.